# How do I pass the IP address typed in the command-line to the client socket constructor in Java?

Tags: java, client-server

I do not know how to read the IP address and use it when I am initializing a socket.

How do I do that?

Here is my socket code on the client side, if needed:

```
 Socket socket;
 socket = new Socket("localhost", 16789);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Echo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (String s: args) {
            System.out.println(s);
            Socket socket;
            socket = new Socket(s, 16789);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this code would parse multiple command line arguments. If you only have one you can use `args[0]` and get rid of the `for` loop.